# what does permission d--------- means

Tags: gnome-terminal, chmod

I just run `chmod 765 -r ./` hoping the last part(`./`) would enable me to run the command on the current working directory. That current working directory was my laravel project. Now I couldn't access it and when I run `ls -l` I see `d---------` in front of it.

Does that mean I don't have any control over it? Including running another `chmod 777` command because when I try to do it, I get permission denied.

Comment: `d------` means directory and you removed all permission to it hence the `-------`. Do a `chmod -R 775 /path/to/dir`

Comment: Try `sudo chmod`. I wouldn't use `-r` and `/` in the same command a typo can destroy your system. I use `chmod a+x script_name` instead.

Comment: Yes, looks like I freaked out, I run `sudo chmod -R 777 /path/to/dir/` like you guys suggested and all is good.

Comment: 777 is bad mojo. do 755 or 750, instead.

Comment: Definitely, I have reverted back to 750 now. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$ chmod 0000 Foo
$ ls -l
d---------  2 myuser mygroup 4.0K Aug 29 20:33 Foo
```

`d---------` means a directory with 0000 permissions

Here is how i 'repair' permissions on a 'in /home/$USER' directory:

```
# recursively Restore ownership of directory
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /home/$USER/Path/To/Dir/

# Set perms on directories
find ~/Path/To/Dir/ -type d  -exec chmod 0750 {} \;

# Set perms on files
find ~/Path/To/Dir/ -type f  -exec chmod 0640 {} \;

# Set perms on sh script files
find ~/Path/To/Dir/ -type f -iname '*.sh' -exec chmod 0750 {} \;
```

Comment: it's notable that 755 & 644 will be acceptable for most people. the 0 at the end does make the security a bit more strict, but that's not necessary for most people.

Comment: @rm-vanda to be honest, i edited 755 & 644 to 750 & 640 because it was too low sec for a practice. But you are right according to the default mask.

Comment: It helped me also with "d????????? ? ? ? ?"!!! There was a flag "S" for files and "s" for directories set for groups. After resetting this flag and changing all ownerships from same to same and finally resetting the directory mods it was working. Don't know what happens!!